# Bootstrap Form Children Elements Exceeds Parent Border

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

My bootstrap website looks like the image below in a large screen.

[image]

But when I transfer the browser to a smaller screen, the child elements of the form exceeds the form border. See image below:

[image]

How will I keep my children elements don't exceed its parent?

Comment: Please share the code bootstrap there must me column count wrong it seems that the smaller screen is taking padding due to bootstrap "col" as parent is outside and child inside it is taking padding in smaller screen

Comment: Yeah bruh, we need the codez, your def doing something wrong that should be easily found. This defies what bootstrap grid is meant to do, so it should be a quick fix. Also if your setting fixed widths on your children that could be a problem too. This should also be downvoted until he posts the code. Poor format.